# What does a colon (:) mean as a mathematical symbol in the context of mapping?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, arithmetic, recursion

I am trying to understand the principle of recursion:

> Let  ℕ  be the natural numbers.
>
> Let T be a set.
>
> Let a ∈ T.
>
> Let g: T → T be a mapping.
>
> $$\forall x \in N: f \left({x}\right) = \begin{cases} a & : x = 0 \\ g
> > \left({f \left({n}\right)}\right) & : x = n + 1 \end{cases}$$
>   [Wiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Principle_of_Recursive_Definition)

Could someone elaborate on what the *':'* symbol implies? Judging from the reference at [Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Colon.html) I believe my concept of what exactly a mapping is may be faulty, especially in the latter half of the equality.

Comment: As a further aside, sometimes you will see something like $f(x):=\dots$ where here $:=$ represents the phrase "is *defined* as being equal to" and is used similarly to ordinary equals signs but emphasizes the notion that what follows is either by definition or being introduced as a definition.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are three different uses of the colon in that passage. In $g:T\to T$, it’s simply part of the standard notation for a function from one set to another: $g$ is a function from the set $T$ into the set $T$. In terms of ordinary English punctuation, the colon after $\forall x\in\Bbb N$ could just as well be a comma: ‘for each $x$ in $\Bbb N$, $f(x)$ is equal to ...’. The two colons in the definition of $f(x)$ should be read ‘if’.

> For each $x$ in $N$, $f(x)=a$ if $x=0$, and $f(x)=g\big(f(n)\big)$ if $x=n+1$.

Comment: By "inn", do you mean "in and only in"?

Comment: @John: No, that was just a typo.

Answer (score 3):

In mappings (such as $f: X \to Y$) it just means, in my eyes, "that maps to", while in the function defined, it just means "such that." Nothing too special.

Comment: Then what does a: x=0 mean?

Comment: "$a$, if $x=0$."